# Creating sub-content based on csv file in parent (plone dexterity)

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have created two content types in Plone 4.3 via Dexterity and created a Plone Product on the file system.

The types are

- Supplier
- item

Items can only exist in inside Supplier, and I can manually create new items without

I'd like to be able to create a bunch of items if I upload a CSV file while creating a supplier. Any way dexterity supports this (trigger, custom view...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to handle that in a custom view. There is no pre-existing code to handle that.

For simple cases, just read the uploaded file with the `csv` module and use the rows to create items in the `Supplier` container:

```
from plone.dexterity.utils import createContentInContainer
import csv

reader = csv.reader(uploadedfile)

for row in reader:
    createContentInContainer(supplier, 'your.package.item', title=row[0], ...)
```

For more complex operations, you could build a `transmogrifier` pipeline with the [`transmogrify.dexterity`](https://github.com/collective/transmogrify.dexterity) to convert CSV-data to dexterity objects, but that is probably overkill here.

Comment: How do I handle the post trigger? Meaning I type in the info for supplier and hit submit (like custom adapters in PloneFormGen)?

Comment: @PeterB: With a [custom view](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/custom-views.html) I'd say.

Comment: I have now found a solution based on your suggestion with a custom view. Thanks for your help